# Inform browsers that they should refresh their DNS cache?

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, web-server

We have a failover setup for our webserver, where we mirror our live webserver in case of some kind of hardware or connectivity failure. At the moment, the process requires us to update the DNS, which obviously is at the mercy of propagation and caching. Propagation these days is pretty quick, but it seems that caching is becoming more sticky.

We haven't bothered going to a more complicated load balancing solution because there hasn't been any reason to do an unexpected switch from live to failover in the almost five years since we implemented the setup. The live server hardware is high spec and robust, using RAID for storage, and is co-located in a big datacenter with huge diesel generators and multiple big fat internet pipes. Even the massive statewide power outage we had last year didn't affect our server and sites.

But we do use the failover for planned outages - like performing site updates that occur once every 6 months. We make the switch in our DNS, and then have to wait for traffic to stop on the live server so we don't disrupt our users too much while updating.

So, is there a way for Apache HTTPD (some kind of HTTP header) to tell users' browsers that they should flush their DNS cache for our domain?

Answer (score 9):

The problem with your question is the flawed assumption that the client browsers have anything to do with DNS resolution. In almost all cases, they don't. They let the underlying OS's DNS resolver handle name resolution and caching mechanics.

If your failover strategy is tied to a DNS record change, your only option for a quicker client turnaround is to lower the [TTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) value on the record in question. The TTL is what determines how long a client caches the result of that record lookup. *Note: It's also possible to lower the TTL on an entire DNS zone. But that's not likely what you want or need here.*

Migrating to a more traditional load balancer works around your problem by putting a virtual/floating IP address in front of the real server's IP so you don't have to make any DNS changes and your failovers can be more or less instantaneous.

Comment: Thanks - I think I'll try and pass this over to our systems guy to worry about - I'm more dev than ops... but I basically want him to do something like "www 600 IN A 127.0.0.1"?

Comment: Definte upvote for "network load balancer" solution.  Not only does this allow you to "switch traffic over" to a standby server on the fly, it also allows you to scale up to multiple web servers if your traffic load starts to impact server performance.

Comment: @HorusKol Yes. 600 would mean that clients (and their upstream resolvers) should only cache the result for 10 minutes. This will obviously increase the load on your DNS server hosting the zone. How much increase will depend on what the current TTL is and how popular your site is.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe asking people to flush their DNS cache is practical. Most average people don't know what DNS is, don't know what a cache is, and wouldn't be able to flush their DNS cache even if you provided phone based technical support. Think about having to flush a DNS cache in a router - there are hundreds of models of routers. If your customers are all highly technical, maybe it's a bit more practical, but consumers, no.

I think you need a technical solution you can control.

You're probably best using a DNS service designed for this, like AWS Route 53. R53 can be used with any servers, anywhere, not just AWS servers / services. R53 can work somewhat like a load balancer, there are multiple [routing types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html) - failover, weighted, latency, etc. You could use [failover routing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html) so it automatically routes to the backup server if the primary goes down.

Another option, which I'm fairly sure won't work, is using multiple A records. The question here is which record will browsers use? From what I've read my impression is browsers should use the A records randomly, but they don't, they use the first one - though I don't know how "first" is defined. Services that distribute load using DNS tend to randomise the order of the IP addresses returned.

Another option, mentioned in the comments, is a reverse proxy. I didn't include this originally because it would mean more hardware. If you put a reverse proxy or load balancer in front of the server/service it can redirect traffic to wherever it needs to go. My suggestion above of using Route53 would perform a similar function, not quite as well, but probably a little better than standard DNS.

A 302 temporary redirect could potentially be used, but you'd need a server that can consistently send those redirects while the main server is down. That would require additional hardware, though not very much hardware.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really want to get users involved - I was looking more for a header which instructed the browser (or proxy) that the server they just accessed is not the correct one anymore. I'll look at Route 53, thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could use 301 redirects and give the backup server another domain name or IP address. But for a 301 to work your web server has to be up to serve it.

Comment: If you had a reverse proxy in front of both the main and backup servers, you wouldn't have to change DNS to do planned maintenance/updates. DNS would always point to the reverse proxy and you could just reload the proxy config to switch servers.

Comment: @Diogenes deLight: That could get tricky - I'm not really a network admin - is this possible if the main and backup servers are in separate physical locations?

Comment: A 301 redirect is a very bad idea here. Browsers will cache the redirect. 302 redirect is better, but that will most likely screw up the application.

Comment: A reverse proxy doesn't care where the upstream endpoint is.

Comment: Yes, @HorusKol, it's possible and should be easy. I can provide you more information as an answer, but meanwhile, see [the nginx instructions](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy)

Comment: I've expanded my answer based on these comments. Totally right 302 not 301. Reverse proxy / load balancer would work but question didn't seem to want that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for Apache HTTPD (some kind of HTTP header) to tell users' browsers that they should flush their DNS cache.

No such mechanism exists, all modern web browsers and the code they execute run a in sandbox from which they shouldn't be able to change OS settings.

Comment: don't the browsers maintain their own cache? I didn't realise they relied on the system cache - so yeah, I understand it's not possible

Comment: browsers maintain a cache of content, not DNS records.

Comment: Does anyone have a reference for "browsers don't cache DNS", or a test? I change IPs in a hosts file occasionally, I find it best to close the browser, flush the DNS cache, then start the browser again.

Comment: Which DNS cache you are flushing exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Local DNS cache isn't managed by users' browsers. It's managed at the OS level. Changing the local DNS cache is an administrator activity. For security reasons, browsers are not designed to execute administrative functions on their host machine.

What you need is a server-side solution. A common solution for this type of problem is to use a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) such as [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/resources/glossary/reverse-proxy-server/), or [apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension).

To do that in a way that allows both your main and backup servers to have downtime, you can run the reverse proxy in a virtual machine that has one or more dedicated IP addresses. That way you (or your cloud provider) only has to maintain the VM; the hardware supporting it can fluctuate.

Your setup would then be:

- Public-facing VM: www.yourdomain.com
- Backend main server: <ip address for main>
- Backend backup server: <ip address for backup>
- DNS for your website points to the VM www.yourdomain.com

If you use nginx, public websites to be proxied are stored as file definitions in the sites-available directory and activated by sym-linking them to the sites-enabled directory. You could either have one site definition per backend server and switch them by changing the symlink or you could have one site definition with a proxy_pass directive for each backend machine, but with one of those directives commented out.

Whichever way you set that up, to switch backends all you have to do is change the site file, then tell nginx to reload its config: `service nginx reload`.

Here's an example site file with a proxy_pass directive for each backend and one of them commented out:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://<ip address of main>:80;
            # proxy_pass         http://<ip address of backup>:80;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

You can do much more than this, including caching static content on the reverse proxy, but this much should get you started.